# Updating column wise in Google Sheets API V4

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I have an AWS Lambda function which writes to this Google Sheet certain performance parameters every week.

[image: google sheet]

If you see the image, I need to update the columns as the weeks progress and see how the parameters change with time. Basically, I would like to know if the Google Sheets API V4 supports column updating.

The documentation says to specify the exact rows and columns and the data in JSON format for the updating to be done. In my case, the column number has to keep on changing each time the function is invoked. I am using node.js as my language.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you take a dip by running the [Sheetsv4 NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) and then experimenting with the [Read and Write](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values). Updating sheets uses the [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).

Comment: Thanks mate. I will try that.

Comment: If you flip your table, you can use `append` rather simply. It's generally easier to work with series as columns rather than rows, and it's a lot easier to compare values in the same column vs in the same row.